# Program to obtain code file for active window

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, process-explorer

I have [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) v15.13.  It works OK.  I can tell which process an active window belongs to.  On the other hand, the PE debugger says its not compatible with VS 2010 (Or at least team explorer 2010 MSSCCI).

I would like to be able to pinpoint the .cs designer code related to the active winform.  Is this possible to do with any program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process Explorer should tell you the name of the form. Decompile the app using (dotPeek) and search for the name. All the designer code will be there for your viewing pleasure.